# Java Integer array indexOf

Tags: java, arrays, null, integer, int

I created an Integer array and I want to insert an index of a string;

```
indexes[i] = theText.indexOf(R.getString(0), i);
```

But I get an error about using indexOf.

How can I fix that?

*I can't change the array to int because I have a comparison of array index to null

Thanks!

Comment: *But I get an error about using indexOf.* > What was the error? Did it happen at compile time? run time?

Comment: What error, and what's the type of `theText`?

Comment: If you epect an answer, you should provide more detailed information, like John Skeet said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indexes is array of Integers?
Maybe you are using Java 1.4. It doesn't support autoboxing. Try

```
indexes[i] = new Integer(theText.indexOf(R.getString(0), i));
```

Answer (score 0):

theText.indexOf returns an int.  You need to convert it to a string e.g.

```
indexes[i] = new Integer(theText.indexOf(R.getString(0), i));
```

Assumptions:

1. indexes is an Integer[]
2. theText IS-A String

This must be pre Java 5, otherwise autoboxing would convert the int returned by indexOf into its boxed Integer class.

Comment: in the question is stated that it is an Integer array

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem is in the type, you can use the Integer constructor:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer(int)